# How to write a gem to rewrite scaffold-generated files

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

We can use `scaffold` to quickly build pages.

But what if I want to customize the `index.html pages` and `form pages`

Every time when I invoked `scaffold` then it will overwrite the customize pages for me.

I want to acheive this by a gem, is there any recommend case can let me study.

I know how to build a gem by bundle,

But I don't know how to hook with `Rails scaffold`

Thanks

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#customizing-your-workflow-by-changing-generators-templates